# Wrong Answer using `get` method of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, get

While solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem) question, I am getting wrong answer on some of the test cases of the problem using the `get` method of `ArrayList` directly in condition check.

Code failing the test cases:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        Stack <Integer> s= new Stack<>();
        ArrayList <Integer> m= new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            if(x==1){
             int y=sc.nextInt();
             if(m.isEmpty() || y>=m.get(m.size()-1))
                 m.add(y);
             s.push(y);  
             
            }
            else if(x==2){
               // Here I am using `get` to check the last value of ArrayList with the top of stack
               if(m.get(m.size()-1)==s.peek()) {
                   m.remove(m.size()-1);
               }
               s.pop();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(m.get(m.size()-1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when assigned the same syntax to a variable and used that for the condition check it passed.

Code passing all the test cases:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        Stack <Integer> s= new Stack<>();
        ArrayList <Integer> m= new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            if(x==1){
             int y=sc.nextInt();
             if(m.isEmpty() || y>=m.get(m.size()-1))
                 m.add(y);
             s.push(y);  
             
            }
            else if(x==2){
                // When assigning the same to a variable it passed all test cases.
                int a = m.get(m.size()-1); 
               if(a==s.peek()) {
                   m.remove(m.size()-1);
               }
               s.pop();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(m.get(m.size()-1));
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

As I am new to Java, I am confused with the use of the `get` method of the `ArrayList`. Please explain to me about the inner working of the `get` method that why it is failing or am I missing something?

Comment: have you checked the documentation of ArrayList? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: @Stultuske yaa I have checked it...but it's still not clear where is the issue with the prior code...

Comment: you're not being clear as to what the issue is. Could you please elaborate, and post a minimal reproduction example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is related to automatic boxing/unboxing of Integer type.
In the statement

```
 if(a==s.peek())
```

the comparison is done comparing the an integer value (a) to the unboxed Integer (s.peek()).

In the statement

```
 m.get(m.size()-1)==s.peek()
```

the comparison is done comparing between two Integer values, that is between two references. Since the two references are different the equality check fails.

To fix the latest statement you can use:

```
 m.get(m.size()-1).intValue()==s.peek().intValue()
```

Or use the equals method of Integer type.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the task itself (as a question should be self-contained and I'm not going to visit random links) but I believe the problem comes from types you use here.

In the first case, `m.get(m.size()-1)==s.peek()` both right side and left side are `Integer`s. Because of that, when you use a `==` sign, you are actually comparing object references. Such comparison will work only sometimes (I believe its for Integers in range from -128 to 127). You could use `equals` to fix the issue.

On the other hand we have `int a = m.get(m.size()-1); if(a==s.peek())`. Here, in the first part you're getting `Integer` first but then it is assigned to an `int` variable - unboxing happens here. Then, when you have a condition, you compare an `int` and an `Integer`. In such comparison, the `Integer` gets unboxed to an `int` and a comparison on simple `int`s happen here (see first point in [JLS-5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)). Because of that it works alright in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...I will update the question...

Answer (score 1):

`s` and `m` store `Integer` objects and you should **never** compare objects using `==`.

Replace `m.get(m.size()-1)==s.peek()` with `m.get(m.size()-1).equals(s.peek())` and your code will work.

The reason that your second approach works is that by assigning `m.get(m.size()-1)` to an `int` variable the `Integer` value is unboxed, and then the comparison `a==s.peek()` is done on the `int` values (the value from `s.peek()` is unboxed too).